# Installation Question for a Windows XP machine

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a machine with Windows XP, and I was hoping to install it beside Windows and not wipe the whole hard drive clean.  I read the installation instructions on the site.  I loaded Ubuntu from a thumb drive.  On load, I clicked the option to install, but when I get to the part of the instructions where I would expect it to let me choose to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, the option isn't there.  I only get an option to erase the hard drive and start a fresh install, or "something else".  Does anyone know what I can do here?

Thanks for any help for a new Ubuntu user.

Comment: If you know what you are doing, you can choose "Something Else". It lets you manually partition your harddrive and install ubuntu on that partition, which is basically what the missing option would have done for you. But I don't know why the "Ubuntu Alongside Windows" option isn't appearing. maybe a corrupted installer?

Answer (score 1):

you can manually install ubuntu.
- select 'something else'
- follow the instruction [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

after the installation, boot into newly installed ubuntu and run this command

> sudo update-grub